# Coefficient Interpretations

Tags: interpretation, least-squares, regression-coefficients

My regression equation is the following:

dit = αdit-1 + γyit-1 + xit-1β + µt + δi + uut, where dit is my democracy score, and yit is my independent (income) variable. The rest are coviariates, time effects, and error term.

Now, I have an estimated coefficient of 2.8(γ). I would like to know how much this coefficients explanation has for the dependent variable.
I would like to write the following: Let's take Ghana which is close to the 25th percentile of the income measure in our sample (7.05), and Thailand which is close to the 75th percentile (8.79) as an example. The income difference predicts a (8.79-7.05)x 2.8 = 4.9 democracy difference between the countries. The actual difference is 10 democracy points, so the estimate explains about half of the observed difference in the said democracy-index of the two countries, which is a lot, or ?
Does this statement makes sense ?